# How can I run AWS Lambda locally and access DynamoDB?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I try to run and test an AWS Lambda service written in Golang locally using SAM CLI. I have two problems:

1. The Lambda does not work locally if I use .zip files. When I deploy the code to AWS, it works without an issue, but if I try to run locally with .zip files, I get the following error:

   A required privilege is not held by the client: 'handler' -> 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbvrpc0a9\bootstrap'

If I don't use .zip, then it works locally, but I still want to deploy as .zip and it is not feasible to change the template.yml every time I want to test locally

2. If I try to access AWS resources, I need to set the following environment variables:

   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
   AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

However, if I set these variables in template.yml and then use  **sam local start-api --env-vars** to fill them with the credentials, then the local environment works and can access AWS resources, but when I deploy the code to the real AWS, it gives an error, since these variables are reserved. I also tried to use different names for these variables, but then the local environment does not work, and also tried to omit these from template.yml and just use the local env-vars, but environment variables must be present in template.yml and cannot be created with env-vars, can only fill existing variables with values.

How can I make local env work but still be able to deploy to AWS?

Answer (score 1):

For accessing AWS resources you need to look at IAM permissions rather than using programmatic access keys, check this document out for [cloudformation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-create-an-aws-iam-policy-to-grant-aws-lambda-access-to-an-amazon-dynamodb-table/).

To be clear virtually nothing deployed on AWS needs those keys, it's all about applying permissions to X(lambda, ec2 etc etc) - those keys are only really needed for the aws cli and some local envs like serverless and sam

The [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/blog/framework-example-golang-lambda-support/) now supports golang, if you're new I'd say give that a go while you get up to speed with IAM/Cloudformation.